# Looping through a row and copying each cell In a specific procedure

Tags: excel, vba, loops

What I have to do is use Excel VBA to:

1. login to Amazon Seller
2. open a workbook
3. loop through a column to get an order number
4. put it in the search box
5. hit the search button
6. go to the order page and extract the data
7. then have the extracted data go back into a specified column in
   another Excel workbook

The loop and order number parts are what I'm currently stumped on. I've figured out this much code as of this moment:

```
Sub MyAmazonSeller()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
Dim oSignInLink As HTMLLinkElement
Dim oInputEmail As HTMLInputElement
Dim oInputPassword As HTMLInputElement
Dim oInputSigninButton As HTMLInputButtonElement

'InputSearchOrder will be the destination for order numbers taken from the workbook
Dim InputSearchOrder As HTMLInputElement

Dim InputSearchButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim AAOrder As Workbook
Dim AAws As Worksheet





MyURL = "https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/homepage.html"

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

' Open the browser and navigate.
With IE
    .Silent = True
    .Navigate MyURL
    .Visible = True
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End With


' Get the html document.
Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

' See if you have the sign in link is because you are in the main
' page
Set oSignInLink = HTMLDoc.getElementById("signin-button-container")
If Not oSignInLink Is Nothing Then
    oSignInLink.Click
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End If

' Get the email field and the next button
Set oInputEmail = HTMLDoc.getElementById("username")
Set oInputPassword = HTMLDoc.getElementById("password")

' Click the button and wait
oInputEmail.Value = "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.net"


' Get the password field and the sign in button
Set oInputPassword = HTMLDoc.getElementById("password")
Set oInputSigninButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sign-in-button")


' Click the button and wait
oInputPassword.Value = "xxxxxxxx"
oInputSigninButton.Click
  Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Set AAOrder = Application.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Employee Folders\Employee\trackingnumber_sample_spreadsheet.xls")
Set AAws = AAws.Worksheets("PrimeOrdersWithNoFulfillmentRe")

Set InputSearchOrder = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sc-search-field")



'What I'm currently stuck on
InputSearchOrder.Value = "001-7163923-7572632"



Set InputSearchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("sc-search-button")(0)
InputSearchButton.Click
  Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

'Was able to add this snippet, but I'm getting an error 13, most likely with 
  'my e variable. I'm basically trying to do a loop within a loop, extracting 5 
  'pieces of data and sticking them back into their respective columns in the 
  'original Excel sheet. The problem comes when scraping the HTML. I'm basically 
   'trying to get text in the tables which have a few levels and it's frustrating 
   'me to no end.

```
With HTMLDoc

Set elems = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each e In elems
    If e.innerText Like "*1Z*" Then
    Range("D2").Value = e.innerText
    End If
Next e
End With


Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. It's been a long week for me with this project haha.

Comment: No, your format is much better. It's more concise and straight to the point. I just need to learn not to write in compound sentences when I'm posting here. :)